# Put the link to the image in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div contain the image inside it like this :

```
<div class="gallery clearfix"> 
<img id="medium-image" src="test.gif" alt="Product Specification" width="230" />
</div>
```

This is what I want to do :

```
<div class="gallery clearfix"> 
<a href="blahblah"><img id="medium-image" src="test.gif" 
alt="Product Specification" width="230" /></a>
</div>
```

This is the jquery that I tried:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#gallery").click(function () { //The link that will be click 
   var path_detail = $('#medium-image').attr('src');
   $('#medium-image').wrap('<a href="' + path_detail + '" class="promotion"></a>')
 });
});
</script>
```

But It doesn't appear anything like what I want. I have no idea about that. Anyone can share some idea please.

Thanks.

Comment: What appears on html after the button click? Does your console have any errors?

Comment: There's no error in error console.

Comment: The above code should work  ... Is this the only code you are using? Does jquery  work at all ? try $("#gallery").click(function () {alert(1)});

Comment: When I click on the #gallery first, it created the link like what I want, But since the second of my click, the link is increase ++ like `<a class="promotion" href="1763.jpg"><a class="promotion" href="1763.jpg">img width="230" alt="Product Specification" src="1220.jpg" id="medium-image"/></a></a>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit neater than building the entire HTML string:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#gallery").click(function () { //The link that will be click 
        var path_detail = $('#medium-image').attr('src');
        var $a = $('<a/>').attr('href',path_detail).addClass('promotion');
        $('#medium-image').wrap($a);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I put your code in JsFiddle and it looks fine to me:

Your Code: http://jsfiddle.net/pSuA7/

The only thing that I add was your #gallery link that needed to be clicked to apply wrap on the image. When you click on the link then  will apply on your mediuam-image.

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery clearfix"> 
    <img id="medium-image" src="test.gif" alt="Product Specification" width="230" />
</div>
<a id="gallery" href="#">Make image clickable!</a>
```

jQuery:

```
 $("#gallery").click(function () { //The link that will be click 
   var path_detail = $('#medium-image').attr('src');
   $('#medium-image').wrap('<a href="' + path_detail + '" class="promotion"></a>')
 });
```

I hope this helps :-)